# Crystal query to sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm not sure how to ask this question. I need to convert this

```
MACHINE HOURS [@HrsMachine]:
if left({Employee.First_Name},1)="8" then {Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs}+{Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs} else 0
```

Crystal Report query to a sql query. I understand the table names.column part but I don't understand what the numbers that come after are, ie.

> left({Employee.First_Name},1)="8"

Is this right? If Employee first name has an 8 in it, then Job Operation Time Actual Setup Hours plus Job Operation time Actual Run Hours, otherwise return nothing.

Can someone help me understand with perhaps some pseudo-code?

EDIT:

Okay I tried

```
SELECT TOP 50 Employee.First_Name, Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs, Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs,
        CASE
          WHEN LEFT(Employee.First_Name, 1)='8' THEN 
            Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs + Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs
          ELSE 0
        END FOO
FROM   Employee, Job_Operation_Time
```

but I'm getting this error: Warning: mssql_next_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/manage/adminer.php on line 673

It's working to some extent as I'm getting the first 50 employees but not the ones that start with the number 8 (the number 8s are machines). I'm not sure if the addition is working either.

Comment: If you want to limit the results to *just* the machines, then you need to add a `WHERE` clause to do so.

Comment: if you are still having issues then maybe take some time to do a SQL fiddle and post here so we can view some of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  ...,
        CASE
          WHEN LEFT(Employee.First_Name, 1)='8' THEN 
            Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs + Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs
          ELSE 0
        END TOTAL_HOURS
FROM    ...
-- remove non-machines
WHERE   LEFT(Employee.First_Name, )='8'
```

** edit **

If you are eliminating everything that isn't a machine, then the formula could be:

```
Job_Operation_Time.Act_Setup_Hrs + Job_Operation_Time.Act_Run_Hrs TOTAL_HOURS
```

Comment: Sorry I messed up I put mysql as a tag but I'm working with mssql using adminer. I used your query though but changed SUBSTR to LEFT (after research mssql functions) and I'm getting desired results for Act Setup Hours and Act Run hours. However, for Employee.First_Name, 1)='8' it's just giving me the first 50 employee names and non that start with the number 8 (which I know there are in the tables) 

Updated my sql based on yours above, please take a look at the error as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
int machineHours = 0;
if(Employee.First_Name.CharAt(0) == 8) // if the first character i.e., left most character
                                      //in an employee's first name is equal to 8
machineHours = Act_Setup_Hurs + Act_Run_hrs;
```

So basically the formula is only adding the hours for employees that have an '8' at the beginning of their name, everyone else gets 0.